# compilation error : cannot convert implicitly type int to bool

Tags: c#

ERROR occurs at for loop

```
List<string> computers = Global.getAllComputers(Environment.UserDomainName);
            computers.Sort();


            if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                foreach (var s in computers)
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (string s in computers)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
                    {
                        if (s.ToUpper() == dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToUpper())
                            continue;
                        else
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ok sorry I identified the issue. i didnt put i < in for loop.

Comment: Title is the question. lol

Comment: @qasali: i don't see any question in `compilation error : cannot convert implicitly type int to bool`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't contain a boolean expression as required by the for syntax, change it to

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
```

By not finding a boolean condition inside the evaluation part of the for loop the compiler complains that you are trying to use an integer (Rows.Count) instead of the boolean expected.

[The For loop C# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)

1. Estabilish the initial value of variable `i`.
2. Evaluate the condition (i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count), the
   value of i is compared to the number of rows in the datagrid. If `i`
   is less than to Rows.Count, the condition evaluates to true, and the
   body of the for loop is executed, otherwise exit the loop
3. Increment the value of i by 1.
4. Return to the step 2 to evaluate the condition again.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 for (int i = 0; dataGridView1.Rows.Count > i; i++)
```

instaed of

```
 for (int i = 0; (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
```